# On assetlinks.json fileupload getting Content-Type application/json error

Tags: json, firebase, react-native, content-type, android-deep-link

I have uploaded the assetlinks.json file in `domain://.well-known/ location`, still I m getting the below error

> It looks like you are hosting the Digital Asset Links file with a wrong Content-Type. Please make sure the Content-Type is application/json

I have used firebase for deployment.

When I hit "`https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://domain:port&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"` for testing.

I m getting

> Error: unavailable: Wrong content type in HTTP response headers while fetching statements from domain

Comment: Please provide the content of your assetlinks.json file.

Comment: Did you figure that out ?